# backup ravenDB database ps script

Tags: powershell, ravendb

Can someone tell me **what command** would I have to use within powershell to perform a **RavenDB backup**

I am getting all of the databases using Rest API

```
$Databases = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($RavenDBURL + "/databases?pageSize=1000000") -UseDefaultCredentials
```

I can filter the List for the database I need. Is there a backup command that I can use to create a backup for a particular database.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the backup operation on a specific database by calling the following endpoint:

`POST: /databases/{name}/admin/backup/database`

Comment: Is POST a ps command. I am getting "The term 'POST:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlt"

Comment: `POST` is the HTTP method. The ps command would be `Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url`.